# Terminology: class is to object as component is to _?

Tags: oop, terminology

This is something that I've thought about several times over the years, especially as it relates to [the UML](http://www.uml.org/).  It came up again in a [recent discussion](http://jbot.rikers.org/#asterisk-scf-dev/20110526.html.gz) (at time:20:38.19 on the linked page).

We have good, solid terminology distinguishing between instances of classes and the classes themselves.  When I say "object", everyone knows that I'm referring to some particular instance that is allocated in memory and is in some state.  When I say "class", everyone knows that I'm talking about some class definition residing in a source file somewhere.

But sometimes it's useful to discuss a system in terms of instances of components.  But there's not a good, general purpose word for expressing that idea, other than "component instance".

Is there a good term that I'm unfamiliar with?

Comment: As far as I can see "Component Instance" is a valid term ^^

Comment: Valid term, yes.  Just not a particularly strong one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I understand it is that UML's "component instance" in normal sense is usually just called "component" or "subcomponent" or "part". And UML's "component" is basically a "component class" or more often "subsystem" i.e. bigger component.